# Automorphisms and cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the group $(Z_n, + \mod{n})$. Describe, with proofs, the set of positive integers $n$ for which both $G = Aut(Z_n)$ and $H = Aut(G)$ are, under functional composition, cyclic groups.

So I need to show what kinds of $n$ satisfy the requirements that both $G = Aut(Z_n)$ and $H = Aut(G)$ are, under functional composition, cyclic groups. (i.e. $n$ is odd, $n$ is prime, $n$ is greater than something, etc...) If I play around with enough finite examples will I be able to get the general idea of what I need to prove, or is there a simpler way to get started?

Comment: I think thinking about what $G$ looks like based on the prime factorization of $n$ should be a good first step. Also, playing around with examples and trying to look for a pattern is never a bad thing. Another helpful idea is, if you know a bit about rings, to look at the ring structure on $Z_{n}$ and use some Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: @ Siddharth Venkatesh I'm still stuck. Regarding $G$, I know that if it is a cyclic group under functional composition, then its elements are bijective functions (isomorphisms) from $Sym(Z_n)$ to $Sym(Z_n)$ and this group of functions must have a generator. Yes? So I need to find the set $X=\{n: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ s.t. $G = (Aut(Z_n), \circ)$ is a cyclic group. And similar for $H$. Regarding prime factorization, I could use another hint...

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh I'm thinking about $G$. Does $G=Aut(Z_n)$ mean the same thing as $G=(Aut(Z_n, + \mod{n}), \circ)$? If so, I'm thinking that $f \in G$ looks like: $f(0)=0, f(1) = a: (a \in Z_n), f(2)=f(1+1 \mod{n})=f(1)+f(1) \mod{n} = 2a \mod{n}, f(3)=3a \mod{n}$

Comment: @SiddharthVenkatesh Am I correct? If so, then $a$ would be my generator for $G$, yes? So $f(j)=ja \mod{n}: j \in \mathbb{Z}$, and I need to determine which values of $n$ allow $G$ to be a cyclic group?

Comment: So, I think you're somewhat on the right track. However, I get the feeling from your questions that you don't know too much about rings. Is that correct? If it is, then I don't know how much help the following hint will be but here goes: suppose $n = \prod_{i} p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}$ is the prime factorization of $n$. Then, you can show that 
$$\text{Aut}(Z_{n}) = \prod_{i} \text{Aut}(Z_{p_{i}^{\alpha_{i}}}).$$
So this immediately tells you that if $G$ is cyclic, $n$ is a prime power. Try and show what I said and then take it from there.

Comment: Also, your thinking in the comments was correct. Any automorphism of $Z_{n}$ is (a) determined by where it maps $1$ and (b) must send $1$ to a number relatively prime to $n$. This might help in proving my hint, although the proof usually uses the Chinese Remainder Theorem and the concept of the group of units of the ring $Z_{n}.$